# Doubly linked list seg faults

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to display a doubly linked list backwards, but every time I try to run anything even remotely touching the "prev" pointer in the program I get a seg fault. 
I've been trying to figure this out for about 4 hours now and I just can't seem to pin it down. I can't tell if the issue is coming from my print backwards function or from the actual prev pointers themselves.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "list.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;     

};

bool LinkedList::addAtBeginning(int val){
    Node *upd8L = head; // This Node will update Last
    Node *upd8 = head;;  // This Node will update the previous pointers
    Node *point = new Node(); // This Node will insert the new node at the beginning
    point->data=val;      // This sets the data in the new node
    point->next=head;         // This sets the next pointer to the same as head
    head = point;         // This sets the head to the new Node

    while(upd8){
    upd8 = upd8->next;
    upd8->prev = upd8L;
    upd8L=upd8L->next; 
    }

return true; 
};

bool LinkedList::remove(int val){
    Node *temp = head;
    Node *trail = 0;
    while(temp != NULL){
        if(temp->data == val){
            if(temp->next == head->next){
            head = head->next; 
            }else{
            trail->next = temp->next; 
            }
        delete temp; 
        }   
    trail = temp; 
    temp = temp->next;
    }
return true; 
};

void LinkedList::printForward() const{
    Node *temp; 
    temp = head;
    while(temp){
        cout << temp -> data << endl;
        temp = temp->next; 
        }

};

void LinkedList::printBackward() const{
    Node *temp = head; 
    while(temp){
    temp = temp->next;
    cout << temp->data << endl;
    }
    while(temp){
    cout << temp->data;
    cout << "Pop" << endl;
    temp = temp-> prev;
    }
};
```

If possible, I'd love an explanation as to what is bugging up my program rather than just a straight answer, I want to know what I'm doing wrong and why it's wrong. 
Thank you!

**edit** 
Here's list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node * next;
        Node * prev;
    };
    Node * head, * tail;
public:
    LinkedList();
    bool addAtBeginning(int val);
    bool remove(int val);
    void printForward() const;
    void printBackward() const;
};


#endif
```

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: no `prev` pointers are touched in `LinkedList::remove`. This bodes ill. Excluding a one element list, you can't remove a link from a doubly linked list without a `prev` pointer somewhere being touched.

Comment: Your `printBackward` function is totally broken. Among other problems, when you break out of the first `while(temp)` loop, `temp` must be `NULL`. So you'll never enter your second `while(temp)` loop.

Comment: Where is list.h?

Answer (score 0):

The function `printBackward()` may cause a seg-fault in the last iteration of the loop. `while(temp)` means iterate till you get the element out of the list `NULL`. Then you assigning `temp = temp->next` where `temp->next` is `NULL`. Now when you are calling `cout << temp->data << endl;` you are trying to get data from `NULL` pointer. Try to change the order. First display the node data, then change the `temp` pointer. An example:

```
void LinkedList::printBackward() const{
    Node *temp = head; 
    while(temp){
    cout << temp->data << endl;
    temp = temp->next;
    }
```

What you are doing wrong is getting the data from a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: You have the wrong fix. The right fix is to change the `while` condition to `while(temp->next)`. The point of that loop is to advance `temp` to the last entry in the list, not to run off the end.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out after a ton of trial and error! 
The biggest issue I was having that kept giving me segmentation errors was whenever I was removing elements of the list I was failing to update the "prev" part of the node, and as a result any time I tried to read the list backwards I was getting a seg error.

```
//put your implementation of LinkedList class here
#include <iostream> 
#include "list.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;     

};

bool LinkedList::addAtBeginning(int val){

    Node *point = new Node(); // This Node will insert the new node at the beginning
    point->data=val;      // This sets the data in the new node
    point->next=head;         // This sets the next pointer to the same as head
    head = point;         // This sets the head to the new Node

    if(head->next != NULL){
        Node *temp = head->next;
        temp->prev = head;
        }
return true; 
};

bool LinkedList::remove(int val){
    Node *temp = head->next;
    Node *trail = head;  
    if(head->data ==val){
            head = head->next;
            head->prev = NULL; 
            delete trail;
            }else{
        while(temp != NULL){
            if(temp->data == val){
                if(temp->next != NULL){
                trail->next = temp->next;  
                delete temp;
                temp= temp->next;
                temp->prev=trail; 
                }else{delete temp;
                    trail->next = NULL;
                }
            }   
            trail = temp; 
            temp = temp->next;
        }
}   
return true; 
};

void LinkedList::printForward() const{
    Node *temp; 
    temp = head;
    while(temp){
        cout << temp->data << endl;
        temp = temp->next; 
        }

};

void LinkedList::printBackward() const{
    Node *temp = head; 
    while(temp->next != NULL){
    temp = temp->next;
    }
    while(temp->prev != NULL){
    cout << temp->data << endl;
    temp = temp->prev;
    }
    cout << head->data << endl;
};
```